# how can i create custom class of uiimageview - swift

Tags: swift

i can create custom uiimageclass file and pass different image in image view class file.

please tell me how to create it in swift 2.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you try something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as i understand from question you asking this snippet

```swift
class CustomImageView:UIImageView {

}
let image = UIImage(named: "some-image")
let imageView = CustomImageView(image: image)
```

Comment: how can i call image view class file for pass image @Ali Kiran

Comment: you can pass image by constructing custom image view class as i show in snippet or later pass by image property.
imageView.image = newImage